# Style scrollbar css colorbox

Tags: css, styles, scrollbar, colorbox

I want to style the scrollbar of the colorbox, showed when the content is larger than the screen resolution. I know how to do this in css (webkit browsers and IE), but I don't know in which part of the colorbox css I need to place the css scrollbar code.

Who does know there to place it in?

Ps. I use iframe: true in the colorbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to the colorbox's CSS in the top middle or bottom, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You would put it in the iframed document.